# Using lucene to index a webpage

Tags: lucene

I'm trying to index webpages with lucene. Therefore, I'm using `doc.add(new TextField("content", webPageContent, Store.YES))` where doc is the document about to be added to the index, and webPageContent is the string of the content of the webpage parsed with JSoup.

Is it the right way to do it - ie, will lucene compute the frequency of each token created from webPageContent?

Comment: `TextField`s are analyzed, so yes, it should.  Are you running into some problem?

Comment: Why not trying and see?